# Sentiment Analysis: using a dataset (IMDB reviews) to train a neural-net and using it to predict entirely different datasets (Political articles)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, sentiment-analysis

We need to analyse a lot of articles relevant to political instability in a given country (things like the possibility of a coalition / a snap election etc). The problem is that I could not find any labeled datasets which could be plugged into a neural network (CNN/LSTM in TensorFlow) so as to supervise it for real-time events (news articles, tweets etc).

I believe we can't use publicly available big datasets - like IMDB film reviews - for training the models to accurately identify and predict the occurrence of such events (or can we?).

Are there other ways to solve this problem?

I also thought of using unsupervised learning - libraries like VADER - but that gives me a more generic sentiment-score, rather than attuned to the specific corpora relevant to the problem.